# Extrapolate historical elasticities

Tags: regression, elasticity

Suppose I have:

- Point estimates of price elasticity of demand for a given good
- Point estimates of income elasticity of demand for a given good
- Point estimates of output for a given good
- Point estimates of monetary income

How may I set such data in a regression context to try to estrapolate historical elasticities (both price and income) for such good? A first thought which came to my mind is that - assuming absolute values are used -  elasticities have a lower bound of 0, and thus cannot be negative. How may I avoid, in a regression context, to produce negative values?

Furthermore I would be grateful if anyone could suggest a regression specification to implement with the data available.

Comment: Take the logarithm. The logarithm is always positive.

Comment: Thank you. How about the interpretation of the log(elasticity) coefficient?

Comment: You can interpret the exp(log(elasticity)) coefficient.

Comment: How about a potential specification?

Comment: The log is the change in percentages.